# Dynamic file path for logging using log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I have two classes(A,B) and multiple threads are running. 
and one global variable in Class B, i am creating object of class B from class A

```
B objB = new B(_istry);
_istry is global variable in Class A and get modifies based on input
```

in Class B
constructor is like this

```
public B(bool istry)
{
    IStry = istry;
}
```

so based on `IStry` value i am writing logs in different file.

```
if (IStry==TRUE)
---normal file path like (C:\log.txt)---
else
---modified file path (C:\IStry\log.txt)
```

this i want to do through log4net but i am not getting how to change folder based on one variable dynamically.

Comment: Easiest is to configure two separate loggers with two separate appenders, and get different loggers in the `.GetLogger` method in the constructor based on the variable. Slightly more involved is one logger with two appenders that filter based on an event property; this requires actually setting event properties, which means you have to explicitly construct events and can't use the `ILog` convenience methods. Alternatively, depending on the scope of what you're logging, a `ThreadContext` could be used to set the property. You could also filter by event message, if you're OK with changing that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert can you provide some example for this explanation.